# Why is the "search" feature not consistent?

Tags: bug, search

Look at this search phrase: `[api.ai] composite entity`

I tried the regular search tool and got 0 results:

[image: Regular search box]

I tried it on your "How to ask" page and got results:

[image: How to ask page with search box]

What am I doing wrong on the regular search?